# How to handle physical quantities in numerical analysis?

Tags: numerical-methods

Hope all are well.  I am interested in learning how to handle physical units in a numerical method.  I have a differential equation that describes fluid's stability (i.e. Orr-Sommerfeld).  In the process of attempting to solve it using a projection method (i.e. Continuous Orthonormalization) I am in doubt how to handle and incorporate the physical units.

I've seen an approach in which the differential equation is converted to a dimensionless equivalent.  The other approach is to leave the differential equation intact.  Both cases are then handled in the numerical method.

My questions are;

[01]-What is the correct approach (i.e. dimension or dimensionless)?

[02]-Is there a good reference book on the subject of handling units in numerial methods?

Thanks In Advance For Any Help

Comment: The units shouldn't matter, as long as they are all consistent, they shouldn't change. Can you ask a more specific question? What is the exact problem your are trying to solve?

Comment: The site [scicomp.se] may be more appropriate here. But try to make the question more specific, for example by including references to those things you have seen..